# WebReference generated namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am really stuck on this problem: I have some data in the class `BigStorage`
and some operations in a GUI. I need to pass data from this class to a web service, and recive an answer and process it.

I have compiled a dll containing  this BigStorage class definition and given it to our web master - he used this class and returned a result to me. But I received this result as 
`webRefName.BigStorage`, which is not equal to my `BigStorage` (they have different namespaces).

By the way one private field in this `webRefName.BigStorage` is `typeof DataSet`(?!) when in my BigStorage it has my own-defined type(I have added xml serialization for it).

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
webRefName.BigStorage bS = (webRefName.BigStorage) bSfromLocalProject;
 //where  bSfromLocalProject typeof BigStorage
```

Also, why this field (see above) in Reference.cs is DataSet?

Answer (score 3):

The types generated from a web-reference are shallow proxy types generated from the metadata (wsdl) available. They are **not** the same as the original types, and cannot be used interchangeably. The namespace can be configured as part of the web-reference's properties, but making it equal will not make this work.

If you have the original assembly used at the other end, consider using a *web service reference* (i.e. WCF). This has the option to reuse existing types, meaning it can use the types from the existing dll reference. Then they are fully interchangeable (or more accurately, they are the same thing - so there is nothing to interchange *with*).

Comment: "reuse types in referenced assemblies" for web ref is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you cannot (by default) cast different types to each other; however, you can define conversion operations in the class which you have access to: if you have access to the web referenced class, then the auto-generated class should be partial and you can extent it; if you have access to the library, then add conversion operation methods to it (although I don't recommend doing this for the library - better do it for the web referenced class).

Basically, to be able to use the code like what you have provided in your question, you either define explicit or implicit conversion in the source or in the destination class.

For reference to the MSDN: [explicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx), [implicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).
In your case it seems that implicit cast is a better fit since this conversion is not prone to the data-losss.

This will look something like this:

```
namespace webRefName {
    public partial class BigSorage {
        public static implicit operator BigStorage(otherNamespace.BigStorage otherBigStorage) {
            //write conversion code from otherBigStorage to webRefName.BigStorage.
            //return the resulting webRefName.BigStorage.
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, this code must reside in the same assembly which references the webservice, because partials cannot be defined in the different assemblies.

After, you can write what you have asked (even without explicit cast):

```
webRefName.BigStorage bS = bSfromLocalProject;
```

I hope this helps!
Tengiz